# MVC 3 HTML validation message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

When all property validation passes but the login info passed in is incorrect, I want to display a model-level error that reads:

> Incorrect login. `<a href="/reset">Reset Password</a>`.

`@Html.ValidationSummary()` is encoding the html.

I have tried creating a custom `HtmlHelper` for this but it's still doing the same thing.

I've also checked the source code and the `ValidationSummary` method uses internal methods that I can't use to recreate a helper for this.

Is there a way, whether in my view or in a `HtmlHelper`, to write an Html message if there is a model-level error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use TempData to solve your problem.

In your method you set the message in

```
TempData["Error"] = "my error <a href=\"url\">link</a>";
```

then from  your view you check if TempData["Error"] is not empty and then with

```
@Html.Raw(TempData["Error"])
```

you should get your message not encoded